# Prove vectors with specific length and dot product cannot exist

Tags: vectors, inner-products

Trying to prove:

> 67. Show that there are no vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $\|u\| = 1$, $\|v\| = 2$, and $u \cdot v = 3$.

Don't know where to go from here:

$$\|u\| = 2 \Longrightarrow \|u\|^2 = 4 \Longrightarrow u\cdot u = 1 $$

$$\|v\| = 1 \Longrightarrow \|v\|^2 = 1 \Longrightarrow v\cdot v = 4 $$

Not sure if this is the right direction to take, but we have:

\begin{align*}
u\cdot v = v\cdot v -  u\cdot u  = 3 \\
= (v + u)\cdot (v - u)
\end{align*}

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the picture. In future, please don't use images where text and properly formatted equations would do, as it makes questions harder to search for, it makes it harder for people with screen readers, and it can mess with how pages display on differently-sized screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ u \cdot v = \|u\| \|v\| \cos \theta $

So

$ 3 = (1)(2) \cos \theta $

which implies

$\cos \theta = \dfrac{3}{2} $

which is not possible.

Comment: Or, similarly, you could also say that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $u \cdot v \le \|u\| \|v\|$, is violated. Note that, in Euclidean space, this is equivalent to $\cos(\theta) \le 1$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to realize the answer:
\begin{align*}
\|u + v\|^{2} & = \langle u + v, u + v\rangle\\\\
& = \langle u,u\rangle + 2\langle u,v\rangle + \langle v,v\rangle\\\\
& = \|u\|^{2} + 2\langle u,v\rangle + \|v\|^{2}\\\\
& = 1^{2} + 2\times 3 + 2^{2}\\\\
& = 1 + 6 + 4\\\\
& > (1 + 2)^{2}\\\\
& = (\|u\| + \|v\|)^{2}
\end{align*}

which violates the triangle inequality.